# multiple fragments in apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

I'm executing a query in Apache drill cluster, however it is making only 1 minor segment. I have tried various queries like union of 2 queries etc, and executing it on 5 million records however it is still making 1 fragment only. Is there any configuration change that I can do for making multiple segments so that these could be executed on each drill bit individually.
How can I confirm whether the query is being executed on 1 drillbit instance or multiple instances.

Answer (score -1):

you can use join to increase fragment.

example:

SELECT t1.name
FROM dfs.`/*` as t1
JOIN(SELECT t1.name WHERE xxx) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE yyyy